# I have a flatlist populated via API as cards, need to achieve share button on each card with there respective data to a new screen

Tags: react-native

Basically, I have a working flatlist data obtained from an remote api & presented as cards. I have added share button in the UI, but not able to figure out,

how I can add on press on each card which when clicked opens more details about that specific card or onclick of share button I can share card specific data or copy card specific data

```
<View>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <CardBox message={item} />}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.Id.toString()}
            onEndReached={() => dispatchFetchPage()}
            initialNumToRender={1}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          />
        </View>

<Card>
        <CardItem button >
          <View style={carddesign.card}>
            <View>
              <Text>Quote by : {this.props.message.author}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={carddesign.cardText}>{this.props.message.quote}</Text>
              <Text style={carddesign.cardSubText}>{this.props.message.genre}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem>
          <Left style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent onPress={ShareQuote}>
              <Icon active name="share" />
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Share</Text>
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon active name="chatbubbles" />
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Copy</Text>
            </Button>
          </Body>
          <Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon active name="download" />
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Download</Text>
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrapp card component inside a TouchableOpacity as follows:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}> 
     <Card></Card>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But my problem is with the on press function, Im not able to figure out how to extract data for a specific flatlist card clicked.

Comment: No problem, just pass your item as a parameter in the onPress function i.e. onPress={this.onPressfunction.bind(this, item)} so you can get the specific item you're pressing.